# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11101110110100011110111011010001"

Tags: java, string, binary, int

I wanna convert String to Binary Integer like this int k = 0B1101.....0111

and the error showen is :

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11101110110100011110111011010001"

```
String a = "1110111011010001", 
       b = "11101110110101010110111011010001";
int K = Integer.parseInt(a.trim(),2);
int T = Integer.parseInt(b.trim(),2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an exception because the 32-bit number that you pass represents a negative integer, so from `parseInt`'s perspective it overflows an `int`.

You have two solutions to parse the number:

(1) Pass a negative representation with a minus sign, i.e.

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("-0010001001011100001000100101111", 2));
```

or (2) pass the original number to `parseLong`, and cast the result to `int`, i.e.

```
System.out.println((int)Long.parseLong("11101110110100011110111011010001", 2));
```

Both snippets produce a negative value of `-288231727` ([demo](http://ideone.com/Ami61L)).

Answer (score 1):

This is because its above the Integer Limits of java.
Try using `long` instead of `int`.